# General techniques to get faster web service response?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, web-services, webservice-client, amazon-product-api

I'm using Amazon Product Advertising API to handle my full text search. The problem is that the response is taking up to 3-4 seconds (which is about half of my total page load time of 6-8 seconds). Are there any general techniques I could do to improve response time? I'm already receiving the response in compressed format.

Ultimately, I want to be able to display the search engine results page to the user as quickly as possible.

Comment: response is taking up to 3-4 seconds (which is about half of my total page load time of 6-8 seconds).  So the Amazon is 3-4 seconds which cannot be changed.  What's the other 3-4 seconds?  That's the only thing that **can** be changed.  What else are you doing?  Please **update** the question with some information on what the other 3-4 seconds are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking about the concept of `Web 2.0`.  Here is where, in your case, you serve the page immediately and then use an AJAX request that will populate it several seconds later with the content - all the while the user sees a spinning animated GIF waiting for your data payload.

You may want to read further about [SOA (Service-oriented architecture)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) - this just one of dozens of programming paradigm that fit with the whole `Web 2.0` theme.

Answer (score 0):

Communicating with external web services is nearly always slow, usually unacceptably so. In this case, the only piece you'll really be able to optimize is the connection overhead. If you were to keep a daemon running locally that maintained a keepalive connection to the Amazon web service, then fired requests through that, you could avoid the connection overhead and improve response times.

From a UX perspective, you're probably better executing the search via an AJAX request to the server. You can display a spinner to the user, and then populate the page when the request returns. This would probably make it feel a bit more responsive, since they wouldn't be waiting on the whole page to build.